# Object type is object[], but when using .length it is now apparently an object

Tags: c#, .net

This function is supposed to return an object array of object arrays,

```
public static object[] testmethod()
{
  var connection = ConnectDB("notesDB.db");
  connection.Open();
  var command = connection.CreateCommand();
  command.CommandText = @"SELECT noteTitle, noteContents, noteID FROM userNotes WHERE noteUserID = '1'";
  var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  List<object> noteDetails = new List<object>();
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(values);
    noteDetails.Add(values);
  }            
  return noteDetails.ToArray();
}
```

When using

```
NoteInfoArray = NotesModel.testmethod();
foreach (var item in NoteInfoArray)
{
  Trace.WriteLine(item);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoteInfoArray.Length; i++)
  {
    Trace.WriteLine(NoteInfoArray[i]);
}
```

over this I get the return

```
System.Object[]
System.Object[]
System.Object[]
System.Object[]
System.Object[]
```

But when I try to index these supposed object arrays, I get

> CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: How you are applying indexing ?

Comment: `noteUserID = '1'` <-- Why are you using a `varchar` type to represent integer values?

Comment: This is a mistake, is should just be ```noteUserID = 1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoteInfoArray[]` is an array of objects, thus it has a `.Length` property.

When you use `object.ToString()` then (unless `.ToString()` has been overridden) it will return the name of the type.

This is what you are seeing when you call `Trace.WriteLine(NoteInfoArray[i]);`.

However, the declared type of `NoteInfoArray[i]` is still `object`, hence if you try to index it you will get a syntax error.

In order to index it properly, you will have to actually cast it to the underlying type like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoteInfoArray.Length; i++)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(NoteInfoArray[i]);
    object[] asArray = (object[])NoteInfoArray[i];
    // Now you can index into asArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, it is enough to cast the object to an array of objects

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoteInfoArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(NoteInfoArray[i]);

    var elementArray = (object[])NoteInfoArray[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < elementArray.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", elementArray[j]);
    }
}
```

The error fire because object is not iterable.